# SQLite al desplegar un proyecto hecho en Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Tengo mi proyecto hecho con Django y lo voy a subir a un servidor que tiene soporte para Django (obvio), pero la base de datos que he usado durante el desarrollo ha sido SQLite.

El servidor Web solo tiene soporte  para MySQL pero mi duda es:

¿Al estar SQLite soportado por Django haría falta cambiar a MySQL o podría seguir usando esta base de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que puedes seguir usando SQLite aunque yo te recomendaría que aproveches el momento para cambiar a MySQL ya que SQLite tiene algunas [limitaciones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#sqlite-notes):

- **Búsqueda de subcadenas con mayúsculas y minúsculas**.

  El siguiente query:

  ```
  filter(name__contains="aa")
  ```

  obtendrá resultados como `Aabb`, `AAbb`. Ten en cuenta que el *lookup* `contains` debería obtener resultados solo para `aa` en minúsculas, para los demás casos existe el *lookup* `icontains` (case insensitive).
- **Errores de tipo "Database is locked"**

  SQLite no es muy buena con la concurrencia, es decir, vas a tener probemas si tu sistema tiene varios usuarios, razón importante para migrar a MySQL.
- **La sentencia `QuerySet.select_for_update()` no está disponible**

  Si quieres sacarle provecho a [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) al usar transacciones, olvídalo, no vas a poder.

Asumo que al estar pasando tu proyecto a un servidor propio o en la nube es porque vas a brindar un servicio a tu empresa, personas, etc. Si este es el caso, entonces:

> ¿Al estar SQLite soportado por Django haría falta cambiar a MySQL o
>   podría seguir usando esta base de datos?

Si, haría falta que cambies a una base de datos mas robusta como MySQL.